# Internet Explorer "Security Information" on every page in https site

Tags: https

My site is using a short vanity URL and https (for admin logins). This is working across all of the custom theme pages in every browser except Internet Explorer. Specifically in IE7, every page I visit in the site presents this warning message:

> Security Information This page
>   contains both secure and non-secure
>   items. Do you want to display the
>   nonsecure items?

Do you think the site being https is causing this? Anything I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your page(s) are loading images, CSS, or JS files that are called in the HTML via non secure mode (http versus https).

Install the Firebug extension on your Firefox browser and look at your URLs that are loading in network tab. Screenshot:
https://skitch.com/noelsaw/rww31/fullscreen

Or you could use Pingdom tools to see what URLs are being loaded. Example:
http://tools.pingdom.com/?url=chase.com&treeview=0&column=objectID&order=1&type=0&save=true

I think you'd have to edit your posts/pages, theme files to specifically call https:// for images, css, and js files.

Comment: Perfect - thank you. After looking in Firebug's Network tab I saw the culprit: the http jquery call. Changed to https in functions.php and no more IE error message!